# Acts as Votable Routing Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently updating a rails app that I made in the past that uses the acts_as_votable gem. The same code worked in the past without any issues. However, every time I try to 'like' a post now, I get this routing error:

> No route matches [GET] "/posts/1/like"

I don't understand why Rails is looking for a GET route when in the past PUT has worked. Here is my code:

Routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    put "like", to: "posts#vote"
    put 'unlike', to: "posts#unvote"
  end
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def vote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.liked_by current_user
  redirect_to: @post
end

def unvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.unliked_by current_user
  redirect_to: @post
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Like', like_post_path(@post), method: :put %>
```

This seems like it should be very straightforward -- I have no idea why it worked before and no longer does.

Comment: Is there a `)` after the `:put` in your code or is it just a typo in your post?

Comment: Unfortunately that's just a typo :( @YanisVieilly

Comment: Have you removed `jquery-rails` from your `Gemfile` by any chance? The `method: :put` option adds a `data-method="put"` to the `<a>` tag created from your `link_to` helper. The `data-method` is then read by `jquery-ujs`, which is included with `jquery-rails`.

Comment: No, `jquery-rails` is in my `Gemfile` and `jquery_ujs` is required in my `application.js` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is trying to map an incoming GET request, and is failing, because, as you stated, the proper HTTP method is a PUT for that URL.  Load up the dev tools on whatever browser you're using, and see what the actual HTML and request look like.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "seeing what the request looks like" but the HTML for the like function is as follows:
`<a data-method="put" href="/posts/2/like" rel="nofollow">Like</a>`

Comment: The data-method attribute does nothing.  You either need to switch the route to a post and use a `button_to`, or use jquery/javascript to issue an AJAX put.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. As @hoffmanc mentions use `button_to` instead of `link_to` and it should work properly.